# PrivateObject instead of Reflection in a production code

Tags: c#, reflection

By the "Reflection" I mean using the System.Reflection namespace.

MSDN says about the PrivateObject class: "Allows test code...". I like a PrivateObject syntax more than System.Reflection one so I wonder is there a real reason not to use it in a production code, and keep it for unittests only?

Comment: `PrivateObject` is for unit testing. Why would you need to access a `private` member otherwise?

Comment: @Romoku, I use a 3rd party control and I need to modify some of it's properties, which are private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `PrivateObject` to actually *reflect* on a type. In other words: You can't use it to get the members of a type.
You can only use it if you know the names of the members beforehand.

That said, I don't see a reason why you shouldn't be allowed to use it, if those constraints don't matter in your scenario.
The class is `public`, well documented and not deprecated.

Comment: So, does it mean that if I _can_ resolve my task by using a PrivateObject then it's _valid_ to use it?

Comment: @aush: I don't see why it wouldn't be. The class is `public`, well documented and not deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

One reason I can give you to not use PrivateObject in a production environment is the need of deploying test assemblies (Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll) to the production server. That's not the place they should be. But if it doesn't hurt any policy from the place you work, it's up to you to decide to use it or not.

By the way, PrivateObject internally uses Reflection, so you're going to use it anyway.

I found this solution to use dynamic objects to call private members (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/01/18/use-c-4-0-dynamic-to-drastically-simplify-your-private-reflection-code.aspx), since you don't like Reflection's syntax. Maybe you should try.

Answer (score 2):

The "real reason" is that private members of a class that isn't part of your project are **not meant to be used or modified by your code.**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)):

> In programming languages, **encapsulation** is used to refer to one of two related but distinct notions, and sometimes to the combination<sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)#cite_note-1)[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)#cite_note-Dale-2)</sup> thereof:
>
> - A language mechanism for restricting access to some of the [object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science))'s components.<sup>[[3]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)#cite_note-3)[[4]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)#cite_note-Pierce-4)</sup>
> - A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the [methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) (or other functions) operating on that data.<sup>[[5]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)#cite_note-5)[[6]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)#cite_note-6)</sup>

The moral of the story is that modifying the private data members of a class or component that doesn't belong to you is akin to *[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*. This means that if you modify those private members, anything could happen—it could work correctly, it could crash your application, or it could format your hard drive.

Instead of using `PrivateObject` or reflection to do something you're not supposed to do, you should consider finding a workaround, requesting a specific feature from the component vendor, or using a different component.

Comment: While true, it doesn't answer the question which basically is "Reflection or `PrivateObject`"

Comment: @Daniel: I disagree: "is there a real reason not to use it in a production code" I explained the real reason not to use it *or* reflection on private members in production code.

Comment: Yeah, but *that was not the question*. The question - as per the title - was "PrivateObject *instead of* Reflection in a production code"