# Why use PrivateObject when we can do the same with pure reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619236/privateobject-instead-of-reflection-in-a-production-code) and I wonder why anyone should use `PrivateObject`. I can't see any value that cannot be achieved by pure Reflection in as many steps. Furthermore `PrivateObject` also uses Reflection.

Are there any usings for that class in favour over Reflection? Consider this:

```
var myProp = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

over

```
var myProp = new PrivateObject(typeof(MyClass)).GetFieldOrProperty("Name");
```

I notice there is a pretty small difference in that I won't need to know the actual access-modifier, but I can't see any further advantage on one over the other? Do you?

Comment: `PrivateObject` is for unit tests. So it doesn't add another dependency to your _unit test project_.

Comment: Sure, I know... but I could also use reflection on unit-tests, can´t I?

Comment: Why use [some high level language] instead of machine code? For the convenience...

Comment: @spender I would agree, if I´d see where the second approach is more convenient than the first one.

Comment: Of course you can also do everything with a hammer. Maybe you have production code that uses also reflection. How do you differentiate between test code and production code then? Always use the right tool.

Comment: It is useful to automatic unit test generators, less code to generate.

Answer (score 1):

Scopes like `Private` are not meant to be a security feature. They are a feature to increase maintainability.

Imagine a software with millions of lines of code and you don't know which classes you are allowed to use and which not.

It makes it easier to have control over your classes and their organization.

Comment: And then `PrivateObject` helps me how?

Comment: when some one uses your code he knows he should use that class outside this boundary. espically when you have multiple assemblies

Comment: The same applies to reflection I guess. So where is the gain?

Comment: But normally you should avoid reflection. Reflection is only for specific scenarios wher you really need it not for normal method calls. There are ways to bypass private but again, it is not a security feature, its a way to organize your code. I strongly recommand you have a look at some of the cleancoders webcasts. www.cleancoders.com

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you in that the syntax for using PrivateObject is kinda verbose.

I searched for something that would use dynamic to expose properties in a less verbose way and found [this](http://igoro.com/archive/use-c-dynamic-typing-to-conveniently-access-internals-of-an-object/)

It uses reflection to expose private fields and methods as a DynamicObject.

Comment: Ah, nice, in particular as private accessors are not longer supported by VS 2011 upwards. However it does not really handle the question on `PrivateObject`. Anyway good solution, thanks +1

Comment: While the link you posted may answer the question, it's always better to include the solution in your answer, at least the most important parts. There are many links on the web that break after a certain amount of time. If you only post the link, your solution will be broken all together with it. Also, your answer could be eventually deleted by the Review flow of SO. Pay attention :)